# How could i show info window for ten markers in google maps?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

dear professionals.

I want to make info window for each markers on google maps.
My code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: content}).open(map, marker);
});
```

show infowindow only for last marker.

Please, give me example or link to tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification of my answer to this question: [Maps API Javascript v3 how to load markers with a mouse click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135904/maps-api-javascript-v3-how-to-load-markers-with-a-mouse-click/5149101#5149101)

It loads an array of markers with info windows, and displays the last one added.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>boats</title>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var infowindow = null;
var map = null;
function initialize() {
    var washington = new google.maps.LatLng(47.7435, -122.1750);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 7,
        center: washington,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    });
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: "loading..." });
    boats(map, seller);
}

var seller = [
['joe boat', 48.0350,-122.2570, 4, 'This is in good shape.'],
['bobs boat', 48.7435, -122.1750, 2, 'This is in bad shape.'],
['bubas boat', 47.3435, -122.1750, 1, 'This is in ok shape'],
['daveys boat', 47.7435, -122.1750, 3, 'dont buy this one.']
];

function boats(map, markers) {

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var seller = markers[i];
        var sellerLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(seller[1], seller[2]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: sellerLatLng,
            map: map,
            title: seller[0],
            zIndex: seller[3],
            html: seller[4]
        });
        var contentString = "content";
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {

            infowindow.setContent(this.html);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }
    // display the last marker infowindow
    infowindow.setContent(marker.html);
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
}
</script>
<body onLoad="initialize()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 450px; height: 350px;">map div</div>
</body>
</html>
```